# Add new images to existing nodes

Tags: 7

I am using imagefield to make photo albums. Now I want to allow all registered users to upload new images to any photo albums and it should get added to the exisiting album. I do not want to give them permission to edit the node. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely have to change what you mean by "edit the node". You could use [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) to restrict what they're able to change when editing the node.

But to truly accomplish this without letting them "edit the node", you'll need a very complex custom solution that would be unreasonably complicated for an answer on this site.

Comment: Does a module like http://drupal.org/project/editablefields would ease the process ?